# Embedding video in beamer pdf with XeTeX/LuaLaTeX to be viewed in Okular

Tags: beamer, xetex, luatex, embedding, okular

The following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\movie[height = 0.6\textwidth, width = 0.8\textwidth, showcontrols]{}{koala.mp4}
\end{document}
```

embeds a video clip into PDF when compiled with pdfLaTeX. This video can be viewed with the Okular pdf viewer. The code, however, fails to compile with XeTeX or LuaLaTeX. How can I embed a video clip so that the code could be compiled with XeTeX/LuaLaTeX, with video shown in Okular? The video file for the MWE is uploaded [here](https://www.upload.ee/files/6218309/koala.mp4.html).

Comment: The canonical package is `media9`. The package you are using comes together with BEAMER. BEAMER's manual suggests that it works with `dvips`+`ps2pdf` and `pdflatex`.

Comment: I need a LuaLaTeX/XeTeX solution  exactly for Beamer, where I'm preparing lectures in the Metropolis theme, which looks pretty ugly with the pdfLaTeX. Media 9, oth, embeds videos in such a way that can't be seen with either Okular or outdated Acroread we have in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using LuaLaTeX, loading the `luatex85` package seems to work out fine.

==============================
LuaTeX v1.0.4
LaTeX beamer v3.41
luatex85 v2016/06/15
okular v0.26.1 with phonon-backend-vlc v0.9.0-2 under KDE Plasma 5 / Debian 9

Comment: I confirm it works with Okular 1.1 under KDE PLasma 5, apps 17.04, GStreamer backend 4.9, openSUSE TW, TeXLive 2017. Many thanks!